# Installing Different versions of iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, version

I recently installed a new OS X on my mac, and installed XCode on it. It provided me only with iOs 6.0 simulator ( and maybe only iPhone 5, I don't really know how to change the simulated device ).

I have a couple of problems I encountered when porting an iPhone 4 project to this XCode, and I want to see if the problem is caused because of new changes in iOS 6/iPhone 5 or simply the code is wrong.

For that reason I want to be able to run the simulator with iOs 4 / iPhone 4, But I can't find a way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode go to:

Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads

then Download the Simulator you need.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you're able to have same iPhone simulators (iPhone 4, 5, 5s, etc) with different iOS version (8.1, 10.1, 11.2, etc).

For latest Xcode, there are couple ways to do that:

1. XCode -> Preference (Command + ,) -> Components. Then install your desired simulators. All other ways will eventually open this window.

[image]

2. Click on your active scheme (pic. 1) -> scroll down to the bottom of the selection pop up (pic. 2) -> click "Download Simulators..."

[image: Click on your active scheme]

[image: scroll down to the bottom of the selection pop up]

3. Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Tab Simulators -> Click plus sign on bottom left corner to open "Create a new simulator" pop up window -> click "OS version" selection -> chose "Download more simulator runtimes ...".

I think by installing the runtimes, Xcode will eventually install all iPhone version that support it, down to iPhone 5.

[image: Devices and Simulators]

[image: "Create a new simulator" pop up window]

Answer (score 0):

You could install all simulator sdks quickly by copying files of sdks from others who has installed them. The file is located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/`. For instance of me:

```
songxiaofeng@xserver:~$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
songxiaofeng@xserver:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs$ ls
iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
```

After copy these files, restart your xcode, you will find these simulators. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in 2020 is to go to Xcode > Preferences > Components and click the download symbol on the versions you want to install.

[image: ui]